# Is this correct or not

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

Greeting to everyone
Recently I attend an interview the interviewer was asked me to demonstrate a single program using constructors, polymorphism, superclass, subclass, interface...
I were written code but they said it's wrong
Help me to rewrite this code with those requirements
my code

```
interface  m1
{
    public  void method();
}
class m2 implements m1
{
    public void method()
    {
        System.out.println("the interface method");
    }
}
class m3 extends m2
{
    public m3()
    {
        System.out.println("Constructor declaration");
    }
    public void method()
    {
        System.out.println("the polymorphism method");
    }
}
public class Allinone {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        m3 obj = new m3();
        obj.method();
        m2 obj2 = new m2();
        obj2.method();
    }
}
```

Comment: You must model the program with things from reality. I suggest you learn about concepts Introduction to programming and then the Java language.

Comment: Is this way of demonstrating is correct

Comment: No, there is still a lot to polish.  The interface syntax, expressiveness, contracts, etc.

Comment: Why did the interviewer *say* that your solution is wrong?  I don't think we can help you if you can't tell us what their reason for rejecting it was.  (And it is pointless for us to try to guess.)

Answer (score 1):

CORONEL Braian is correct, your code isn't realistic. Perhaps you could have done the frequent example of making an interface `Mammal` and add a parent class `Animal` and work from there (Add child classes like `Dog` `Bird`. However, it would be ideal if you add why your interviewer did reject your answer as Stephen C said.

All the Best!